# Information regarding TLS connection and certificates

Tags: c++, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, private-key

I am new to this TLS connection , certificates area. 
I have certificates and private key to make connection with server;i am trying it with openssl. I am confused if i have to encrypt private key before sending to the server or use directly? Also,do i have to encrypt all the messages further with this private key?
I have 2 certificates;which api in openssl take 2 certificates for handshake?

Comment: Your best bet is to go and look at how other programs use OpenSSL library. That's pretty much the only way to figure it out.  The documentation that's included with OpenSSL is not that great, and one has to look at the existing code to figure it out. But, in brief: you don't have to do anything of that sort. You just have to tell OpenSSL: here's my certificate, and here's my private key, now go connect to the server. If the server requests your certificate, the library will take care of sending it to the server as part of the protocol.

Comment: Normally only the server has a private key and a certificate. SSL/TLS does support client authentication, but it is not very common, although I won't go so far as to call it rare. Why do you have a certificate and a private key? How did these come into your possession.

Comment: It was an assignment.I was given 2 certificates and private key to connect to the server and then send the specific data to the server.So, i started to try with openssl. I was little unclear of the concepts thats why.One certificate is the root one and other i guess intermediate. But, i tried to put them in one file, it showed as root but it didnot show the other one under the root in certification path.So, i thought to enquire if there is a way to load both separately in openssl.